# Flutter web - How to check current "display" of a Progressive Web App (PWA)

Tags: dart, flutter-web

I want to check if my Flutter PWA has been launched from an installed version.

The manifest.json file has a "display": "standalone" property. How can I check this in my Dart code?

I would like to do something similar to the following:

```
if(currentDisplay == standalone) {
    // do something
}
```